# requested file operation failed in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to read a txt file from my directory and getting the following error. This is the first time seeing it and I don't think it happened to me before. So, just wondering what's going on and how to fix this.

```
$FilePath = 'C:\Users\yzqpsn\Desktop\Audit-Log-Script\teams.txt'
$Data = Get-Content -Path $FilePath
```

```
Get-Content : The requested file operation failed because the storage policy blocks that type of file. For more information, contact your system   
administrator.
At line:1 char:9
+ $Data = Get-Content -Path $FilePath
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (C:\Users\yzqpsn...cript\teams.txt:String) [Get-Content], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentReaderIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

Comment: Does it happen with all text files, or just with that one in particular?

Comment: Are you on a domain-joined computer? Which AV software do you use?

Comment: I'm on not domain-joined computer. also I just created csv file and try to do the same but it giving me the same error.

Comment: Your AV software might block the access. Can you open the file in an editor manually?

Comment: Do you have HP SureClick installed?

Comment: yes I was able to open the csv file or txt file manually. @Theo no I don't have that installed in my laptop

Comment: When looking for that error, I can only find it in combination with Adobe pdf files.. Not .txt files. Are you sure you're dealing with a simple text file?

Comment: Thanks you two for the help. I just figure out that it's because my Desktop was syn with my OneDrive and you are right that when ever I open txt file it view with HP SureClick

Comment: @ziico Nice to hear, that you were able to find a solution. I encourage you to write an answer, as comments might be deleted in the future.